# Will deleting a subscription from iTunes Connect cancel all subscriptions?

Tags: app-store, subscriptions

If I delete a subscription-based product in iTunes Connect, will that cancel all active subscriptions users are having for that product?

Comment: This site is about programming questions.  Since this question is not about programming, I have flagged it as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. (Sorry, I am answering my own question.)

I just found the following on Apples documentation:

*"Important: Removing a product from sale prevents auto-renewable subscriptions from renewing, but it doesn't keep users from being able to restore products that they purchased previously."*

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/WorkingWithYourProductsStatus.html